# Launch a LibGDX Android app from vanilla Android Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, launch

Title kind of sums it up; I am developing an application which the vanilla android portion is handling a GCM service, Google+ Authentication, and the applications lifecycle. The LibGDX portion is a 2d platform game utilizing these features.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to launch the LibGDX app once the user gets to a specific point in the application.

What I've tried, in Eclipse, I have enabled the MyGDX-android as an Android Library, imported it into my VanillaService, initialized and launched the intent successfully. However, as soon as the device tries to launch the MyGDX-android application, it crashes because it can't find any of the resources which are deployed with VanillaService->MyGDX-android.

Is there something that I can do to get it to work using **two separate applications packaged together**

or

Will I have to **merge the vanilla code into the LibGDX app**?

Comment: I believe what you would need to do is create a LibGDX Project so that all the necessary dependencies are given for it (use the new Gradle version or the old one that did not use gradle but the developer's last comment on the repo was "I really think I should delete this turd" heheh), and then instead of using an AndroidConfiguration, you would use the initializeForView() and use LibGDX as a view - but then the app logic would be implemented in the Android project, and given to the "core LibGDX project" through an interface - is what I think.

Comment: So I'd say you'll have to merge the vanilla code into the Android project of LibGDX.

Comment: Set it up as any other libgdx project, with separate core and android projects. In the android project, set up your vanilla activity to manage fragments, and use AndroidFragmentApplication as the fragment representing your game. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-&-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. You want to have a native Android application, and then at some point start the LibGDX Activity, right ?